# Swapping elements between more than 2 arrays

Tags: r, swap

Swapping elements within a single array (x) is a classic problem in computer science. The immediate (but by no means only, e.g., XOR) solution in a low-level language like C is to use a temporary variable:

```
x[0] = tmp
x[0] = x[1]
x[1] = tmp
```

The above algorithm swaps the first and second elements of x.

To swap elements between two subarrays, x and y, is similar

```
x[0] = tmp
x[0] = y[1]
y[1] = tmp
```

What about for the case of 3 arrays with the added restriction that an element of Array 1 must be swapped with an element of Array 2 and an element of Array 2 must be swapped with an element of Array 3? Elements in Arrays 1 and 3 are not swapped with one another.

How can such an approach (with the added restriction) be generalized to k arrays?

Comment: I'm working in R, but in my example indices start at 0 (not 1 like they do in R)

Comment: This brings back memories of the [Tower of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) problem, see the Frame–Stewart algorithm in the link for a generalised approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a for-loop that repeats your set of instructions:

```
l=list(x = c(1,2,3,4,5),y = c(5,4,3,2,1),z = c(6,7,8,9,10))

swap_elements <- function(l)
{
  for(i in 1:(length(l)-1))
  {
    tmp = l[[i]][1]
    l[[i]][1] = l[[i+1]][2]
    l[[i+1]][2] = tmp
  }
  return(l)
}
```

Output:

```
> swap_elements(l)
$x
[1] 4 2 3 4 5

$y
[1] 7 1 3 2 1

$z
[1]  6  5  8  9 10
```

Comment: A for loop is what I currently have. So far it is just for 2 arrays

Comment: So then you have a solution that is generalized to k arrays? I am not sure what you are looking for then.

Comment: Your solution is more succinct than mine (which was not generalized). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if the Arrays are stacked into a matrix, you can lag the rows to create the required action

```
k <- 6

#generate dummy data with k rows and 3 columns
mat <- matrix(seq_len(3*k), nrow=k, byrow=TRUE)
mat

#lag the matrix
mat[c(seq_len(k)[-1], 1),]
```